# Problems sending HTML mail with attachment on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, email, attachment

I'm trying to send a JPG attachment with a formatted HTML message. Of course I'm using [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
The rest of the code is what it is supposed to be, according to various messages on forums.

What I observe: the contents of the resulting e-mail message depends on the configured e-mail account on your iPhone.
E.g.: for a Yahoo mail account, setting isHTML to YES never results in an HTML message, but setting it to NO does! Bug in Apple stuff?

But, for a GMail account, I've never succeeded to send an HTML mail, it is always received as plain text.

The JPG file is sometimes shown inline, sometimes as an attachment.

All I want: send a JPG file, and a message containing some line breaks. Does anybody have some proven code that does just that, working for all kinds of e-mail accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set isHTML param to YES, your message body can be sent as plain/text if the message body can be represented as such. And attachments in plain/text messages are not always recognized correctly by some email clients (Outlook).

In my case adding a link in the message body helped. Formatting text as bold with HTML tags works too. Tricky!

Tested on iPod 1G 3.1.3.